# Grails Criteria on listsize in domain

Tags: grails, group-by, criteria

i've the Domain Class `League`. Each League has a `heightNumber` representing the height of a league (e.g.: 1 = "first League, 2 = "second League") and a `widthNumber` representing same high leagues. So lets say a league with height 3 and width 2 can be seen as the "3.league B". A League has 0 to 16 teams.
I try to find the `best(min(heightNumber)` and `min(widthNumber)) League` that has free team slots `(teams.size()<16)`

```
def league = League.withCriteria(uniqueResult:true){
sizeLt("teams", 16)
    and {
    eq(heightNumber, min("heightNumber"))
        eq(widthNumber, min("widthNumber"))
    }
}
```

I know that the code above doesn't return the desired League.

My League Domainclass:

```
class League {

    String leagueName
    int heightNumber
    int widthNumber

    static hasMany = [teams:Team]


    static constraints = {
        teams(size:0..16)
        heightNumber min:1
        widthNumber min:1
    }
}
```

In other words I need:

```
def leagues = League.withCriteria{
    and {
        order('heightNumber', 'asc')
        order('widthNumber', 'asc')
    }
}
for(League l : leagues){
    if(l.teams.size()<16){
        return l
    }
}
```

this Code now works for me, but I think it is quite inperfomant.
Would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the more flexible hql. I hope this works for you, not tested:

```
League.executeQuery("select distinct l from League as l where (select min(heightNumber) from League) = l.heightNumber and (select min(widthNumber) from League) = l.widthNumber and l.teams < 16")
```

Comment: Not sure if your query does what he wants. I think the goal here is first to select the set of leagues with minimum height (where one width has less than 16 teams), and then find league with minimum width in this set. Your query is equivalent to the criteria in the question.

Comment: I edited my question by adding some code that should make my question more understandable.

Comment: your code throws an error, because you can't call size() on an integer (teams.size()). use instead teams < 16. sorry for providing a wrong query

Comment: teams is a list of Team domain objects, not an integer. But I got my code running using a for loop instead of the .each.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do exactly, but maybe this can help: here is a query that output the league with the smallest `widthNumber`, among all leagues that have the smallest `heightNumber`.

```
League.find("from League as l
             where l.teams < 16 and
                   l.heightNumber = (select min(heightNumber)
                                     from League)
             order by l.widthNumber asc")
```

Doing this using criteria involves sub-queries, which is kind of verbose, as Grails criteria DSL has no support for them.

Comment: hmm, no it's still not exactly what I need, but it may helps me finding a solution. I'll try something and  will then post my progress.

Comment: Well, then tell us what you need precisely.

Comment: By the way, did you look at my comment in the other answer? You have to define which property `heightNumber` or `widthNumber` takes precedence, or somehow derive an ordering from these two properties.